# How can I match some part of request body?

Tags: regex, stubby4j

I am capturing request in [stubby4j](https://github.com/azagniotov/stubby4j) like this

```
-  request:
      method: POST
      url: /someUrl
      post: ".*(amit).*"
```

It works fine if I use single line in request body. E.g. `User name is amit gupta`. But it fails if I use multiline text as

```
User name is amit gupta 
secondline
```

How can I match some part of request body?

Comment: Try  `"[\\s\\S]*(amit)[\\s\\S]*"`. Documentation contains both `\d` and `\\d` examples, I am not sure if the backslashes must be doubled.

Comment: grt thanks. It worked.

Comment: I've been moved to [stubmatic](https://github.com/NaturalIntelligence/Stubmatic) now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by the documentation, you just can use

```
"[\\s\\S]*(amit)[\\s\\S]*"
```

The `[\s\S]` construct matches any character that is either whitespace (`\s`) or non-whitespace (`\S`). Note that the parentheses around `amit` only make sense if you use the backreference to it later, thus, I'd remove these brackets.